# How do I underline a form field a with vertical line at end

Tags: html, css, forms

I have seen many websites with the following design for their form:

[image: form line with vertical tick]

How do you accomplish the vertical tick at the left end of the line?  Is it a pseudo element, or some border hack, or am I completely missing something simple?

Comment: Related to (or possible duplicate of) http://stackoverflow.com/a/34963317/2606013

Comment: There's several ways to do it. Is there a specific website you would like it explained for? You can just use developer tools to inspect their CSS.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/500/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a `::before` pseudo element. Just enclosed your textbox in a div and make its height 50% or as much less as you want. You will also have to use `top` to bring the div down by same amount of height you reduced. `padding` is essential to display the div at exactly left of textbox.

Here is the code and [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vw9geu2L/) demo

HTML:

```
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="t1" placeholder="Your Name">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #t1{
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   border:0;
   border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
   text-align: right;
  }

 div{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0.15em;
 }

 div::before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
 }
```